# Create IPA iOS file for multiple testing devices with Free Apple ID

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, apple-id

I have a **free** personal Apple ID account, I made an IPA file successfully but only works for my own iPhone device, when other testers want to install the IPA on their own iPhone through iTools, they get an "Authentication failed" error at 99% of the installation, I guess it's because that the IPA contains only my device UDID. I searched on the internet that I should add the testers's devices UDID in the Apple Provisioning Portal but, I can't find this page on my account, and I get redirected the welcome page if I try to access directly to that page.

Comment: Do you have developer a/c or user a/c ?   https://developer.apple.com/

Comment: @Hasya like I said, I have a free Apple ID (Personal Team) Free

Comment: Did you paid $99 for same ?

Comment: I never paid a $, like I said it's FREE

Comment: Then you have to go on developer.apple.com and sign in to developer a/c and pay $99 , then only you can add other UDIDs and provide build to others for testing.

Comment: Is your problem resolved? then close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not enrolled on https://developer.apple.com/ with paid a/c then you would not be able to add UDIDs and provide build to others for testing purpose.